# How to run a for loop after a for loop?

Tags: c#

I have a variable 'start' that initializes with a value 0.

How can i switch to a different loop when 1 argument becomes true.

So here is what i am trying to accomplish

when I click the button

1st Loop start with textBlock 1 containing "XXXX"
and Variable'Start' increment's by 1 everytime i click/touch till it reaches 34 . So when the counter reaches 34, the text changes to 'YYYY'

2nd Loop is when the counter resets and starts from 0 again but this time it only needs to go up till 33 .  As soon as it reaches 33 the text changes to 'ZZZZ'.

Last Loop: The counter resets agains goes up till 33 . But this time when it finishes. It goes back to loop 1.

Here is the code that i have right now and I cannot seem to figure out how to do the last loop.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private int start = 0;
    private bool sw = false;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int start = 0;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tasbih();            
    }
    public void tasbih()
    {
        if (sw == false)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "TEXTBX 1";
        }
        start++;
        String text1 = Convert.ToString(start);
        textBlock2.Text = text1;

        if (start >= 35)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "TEXTBX 2";
            start = 0;
            String text2 = Convert.ToString(start);
            textBlock2.Text = text2;
            sw = true;                
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        textBlock1.Text = "Reset";
        tasbih();

    }
```

Also i have a reset button that starts everything all over no matter where you are in the counter. Any pointers as to how i can do that ?

Comment: start property will not preserver a value between clicks

Comment: Do you need to use only a single counter? Or could multiple counters be used?

Comment: I can use any amount of counters. This is what i came up with. But i dont know  how to get all 3 loops working 1 after the other .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a more explicit state variable, and key off of that for all your logic. You're currently keying off of `start` only for the transition to `sw = true`, it'll be easier if you have an explicit state.

```
enum MyState { Part1, Part2, Part3 }


MyState currentState = Part1;
int clickCount = 0;

public void tasbih()
{
    clickCount++;

    // First, do state transitions.
    switch(currentState)
    {
        case MyState.Part1:
            if(clickCount >= 34) { currentState = MyState.Part2; clickCount = 0; } 
            break;
        case MyState.Part2:
            if(clickCount >= 33) { currentState = MyState.Part3; clickCount = 0; } 
            break;
        case MyState.Part3:
            if(clickCount >= 33) { currentState = MyState.Part1; clickCount = 0; } 
            break;
    }

    // Now, act on the current (or new) state.
    switch(currentState)
    {
        case MyState.Part1:
            textBlock1.Text = "TEXTBX 1";
            textBlock2.Text = clickCount.ToString();
            break;
        case MyState.Part2:
            textBlock1.Text = "TEXTBX 2";
            textBlock2.Text = clickCount.ToString();
            break;
        case MyState.Part3:
            textBlock1.Text = "ZZZZ";
            textBlock2.Text = clickCount.ToString();
            break;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentState = MyState.Part1;
    clickCount = 0;
    tasbih();
}
```

Comment: This wont increment click count when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
// these have to be member variables, or you'll never be able to reset
// or even remember the counter between calls
private int clicks = 0;  // the number of clicks in the current loop
private int state = 0;   // which loop we're in

// these are just so we don't have to repeat ourselves.
// each element corresponds to a possible value of `state`.
// both arrays should have the same number of elements.
// alternatively, you could have a type containing the label and max together,
// and just have an array of those.
private string[] labels = { "TEXTBX 1", "TEXTBX 2", "ZZZZ" };
private int[] max = { 34, 33, 33 };


public void reset() {
    clicks = 0;
    state = 0;
    // probably reset text boxes here too.  If you don't want to, then delete
    updateTextBoxes();
}

public void bump()
{
    // bump the counter, and if it's high enough, switch to the next state
    // and reset the counter
    // (the "% max.Length" causes 3 to be 0, so states wrap around)
    if (++clicks > max[state])
    {
         state = (state + 1) % max.Length;
         clicks = 0;
    }

    updateTextBoxes();
}

private void updateTextBoxes() {
    textBlock1.Text = labels[state];
    textBlock2.Text = clicks.ToString();
}
```

Comment: operator '>' cannot be applied to opperand of type 'int' or 'int[]'

Comment: Oops.  Was comparing to `max` rather than `max[state]`.  Updated.